# Azure Speech Service のText to Speechで日本語の出力が欲しい（Unity）

Tags: unity3d, azure

[Microsoft Quickstart](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/text-to-speech?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=unity%2Clinux%2Cjre)を参考に現在Unity上でText to Speechを実装しようとしております。英語ではうまくいくのですが日本語をInputFieldに入力しても、うまくいきません。
[こちら](https://qiita.com/morio36/items/e6ba4de33bb8eb10f887)を参考にしようとしたのですが、すでにBing Speech APIはAzure Speech Servicesとなっているとのことでした。
環境はWindows10、Unity2017.2.1です。
お手数をおかけいたしますが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Qiitaの記事ではSSMLを作って依頼しているようですが、クイックスタートのソースでは素のテキストしか使っていないようです。おそらく、それでデフォルト設定(英語話者)状態でしか処理されないのでしょう。こちら [音声合成マークアップ言語 (SSML)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup)のページを参考に、Qiita記事に相当するような日本語用のSSMLデータを作って依頼してみてはどうでしょうか？ あるいは、SpeechSynthesizerオブジェクトを作る際の[SpeechConfig Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechconfig?view=azure-dotnet)の設定をあらかじめ細かく行っておくとか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。